# error: namespace "cv::cuda" has no member "resize"

Tags: c++, opencv

I have successfully built opencv with `WITH_CUDA=on`. but I'm still facing this error `error: namespace "cv::cuda" has no member "resize"`. it is weird that the IDE suggests me that there is a resize function in that namespace but it fails on compile. Does anyone know how to tackle this matter?

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudev/ptr2d/gpumat.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudev/ptr2d/resize.hpp"
#include "newfile.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int test() {
    cv::Mat LoadedImage;
    cv::cuda::GpuMat Im;

    LoadedImage = imread("in.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    Im.upload(LoadedImage);
    cv::cuda::resize(LoadedImage, LoadedImage, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5, cv::INTER_NEAREST);

    imwrite("Step4a.JPG", LoadedImage);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/db/d29/group__cudawarping.html#ga4f5fa0770d1c9efbadb9be1b92a6452a) you should `#include <opencv2/cudawarping.hpp>`

Comment: @john that really helps. thanks. I did try to include it before but that time I wrote the code in .cpp file and a bunch of weird errors occurred.

Comment: I followed the documentation. It does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @john has pointed out. I should `#include <opencv2/cudawarping.hpp>` to solve the problem.